# What levels are the DLC areas?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2

I downloaded 4 DLC regions which are already unlocked on the world map: Hellfire Grotto, Oblivion Ruins, Way of Saburai and Trinity Steppe. Upon visiting one I found **giant murderous dragon monsters** and immediately ran as they looked 5000x more powerful than anything I've seen before.

What level should I be before trying the DLC areas? Do they each have their own levels?

Comment: They are at different levels, increasing in the order that they are purchased in the DLC. That said, I don't know what level they are - I'm at level 70 and I still can't kill any of them instantly with a map attack.

Comment: @GraceNote sooo don't go to those until I beat the main story or what?

Comment: Something like that. Unless you're cunning enough to be able to take on peops well above your level.

Comment: Cunning? Yes. Handsome? Yes. But I think I'll leave the level 70+ monsters until I'm something over level 24